# Remote Desktop connection and physical monitor black screen

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, ftp, filezilla, teamviewer

I was connected to a Windows 10 PC via Remote Desktop Connection (RDP) from another machine.

I didn't close the connection and when I had physical access to the machine I just turned on the monitor. Normally, it is supposed to be showing the lock screen so that I can login locally to Windows 10. I do this everyday without any issue.

Instead the screen is black, but not in sleep mode.

I still had access through RDP but then I terminated the connection.

Still black screen.

Now, I cannot connect again via RDP since right after it establishes connection, it shows a black screen and terminates (goes back to the login window).

I can connect via TeamViewer but it also shows a black screen.

I have tried pressing Ctrl+Alt+Delete both on the actual machine and via TeamViewer and nothing happens.

The thing is that I have a huge number of files currently uploading via FileZilla FTP and I don't want to reset the machine.

Is there any workaround?

To take it one step further, if I hard reset or shutdown the PC, does FileZilla keep any metadata or cache so that it can continue from the file it stopped? We are talking about 700000 small files that create a huge bottleneck if I try to re-upload since FileZilla will have to check if each of them is already on server.

**EDIT**
Even though I have verified that the files are still transferring to the server, there are like 10000 failed uploads which I didn't readd to the FileZilla queue. So there is no point in just waiting for them to finish if all FileZilla's queues are lost after I hard shutdown or reset the PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the screen replication driver used in RDP did not start/end correctly and as far as I know the only way to fix this is a reboot. The default filezilla behavior is to resume transfers were possible after powerless. So you should be ok to do a reboot, but to save some time i would filezilla into the server it is transferring to and validate the files are still moving. If they are then you can just wait till the transfer is over to reboot.

**UPDATE 1:**

It will resume the uploads according to this previous post.

[Will FileZilla resume interrupted downloads?](https://superuser.com/questions/285635/will-filezilla-resume-interrupted-downloads?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: I have already verified that files are still transferring to the server. The thing is that FileZilla has some failed uploads which I didn't readd to the current queue. So there is no point to just wait. Do you know if the FileZilla queue and the failed transfers list remains after a shutdown?